# Tossing a fair coin probability random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The game is that you keep tossing the coin until you toss the tails. Call the total number of tosses the random variable **K**.

For example:

- HHT -> K=3
- HHHHHT -> K=6
- T -> K=1

so,

- Calculate the PMF for K, Pk(k) = P(K=k)
- Calculate the expected value of K, E[K]
- After each game, you are paid K dolar. What is the expected value of your
  earnings? How much woul you pay to play one round of this game?

for first question:
PMF for K, Pk(k) = P(K=k)

K=1,2,3..... K be the total number of coin tosses.

$P(K=1)=P(T)=p$

$P(K=2)=P(HT)=(1-p)^2p$

$P(K=3)=P(HHT)=(1-p)^3p$

....

$P(K=n)=P(HHHHHH....HT)=(1-p)^{n-1}$

so what can i do?

Comment: yes, but i didnt find the answer :)

Comment: I wrote about displaying effort, not about finding the answer.

Comment: ok i will add my answers.